# socialauth wp Twitter returned an error. Login Failed

Tags: wordpress, twitter, authentication

I'm using http://wordpress.org/plugins/socialauth-wp/ on my site and trying to setup twitter login. Ive created the app and copied what I think is the right secret key and api key into the app

But twitter login fails with

"There was some unexpected error, when trying to login with Twitter

Following are the details of error :

Some strange error occured, Please try again Later...

Error reason: User profile request failed! Twitter returned an error.

« Back to Login Page"

Do I put the API Key: App Secret: keys in from
Consumer key
Consumer secret

Or from the

Access token
Access token secret

fields from my twitter app page? https://dev.twitter.com/apps/5779906/show

Perhaps I have a setting wrong but have tried a lot of stuff now and pretty frustrating.

What do I put for Callback URL: ? My sites homepage? How I get them to go back to the page they logged in from?

Hope someone can help me clear this up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the exact same issue by updating hybridauth within the plugin folder with a copy from the developer.

The socialauth plugin is a wrapper for hybridauth http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/downloading.html which is a wrapper for the twitter api.

The API changed, hybridauth was updated, but the socialauth maintainer didn't update the plugin. HybridAuth abstracts the api and that didn't change so it's just a drop in replacement.